# Existence of injection or surjection between two given sets

Tags: axiom-of-choice

I'd like to know why, given two sets $X$ and $Y$, there always exists an injection from $X$ to $Y$ or a surjection from $X$ to $Y$. In other words, why we can always compare the cardinality of two sets.

I appreciate any help!

Comment: What previous knowledge do you have in set theory? Do you know about the axiom of choice? Do you know about Zorn's lemma? The well-ordering theorem? Do you know Hartogs' lemma? Anything? Something?

Comment: @AsafKaragila I know the axiom of choice and Zorn's lemma. I have just looked up the well-ordering theorem.

Comment: Once you realize that an injection from $X$ into $Y$ is the same as a surjection from $Y$ onto $X$ (as long as $X$ is non-empty), the question has many answers. See the duplicate, as well as the linked questions there: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/421638

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thanks I'll check them out.